# Can't change "Cleared for Sale" for IAP (AppStore)

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store

I want to remove Auto-renewable subscription from App and don't support it in the next version. I made some research and find that I should set parameter "Cleared for Sale" to false in appstoreconnect, but it's not active. I cannot edit this. Any idea?

Comment: @matt how about reading my question? Button not active. I cannot change Cleared for Sale

Comment: i have admin role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admin Role is not enough unfortunately. Only the Account Holder can remove an auto-renewable subscription. You can read more about it here:
https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev636f037c8